# Finding number of pairs in array where A[i] * A[j] > A[i] + A[j]

Tags: java, c++, c, arrays, algorithm

For e.g. if Array A is

```
A[0] = 0.1
A[1] = 0.6
A[2] = 1.2
A[3] = 1.7
A[4] = 3.5
```

then for pair (3,4) we have `A[3]*A[4] > A[3]+A[4]`

I want to find the number of such pairs in an array.

Also `A[i] = A1 [i] + A2[i]/1,000,000`

Where A1 and A2 are inputs given and **A1 and A2 are in sorted order**.

Answering with O(n^2) algorithm is trivial. I am told there is O(n) solution for this without using extra space. I am looking for that.

Comment: O(n) algorithm to find number of pairs in an sorted Array where A[i]*A[j] > A[i] + A[j]

Comment: are the numbers unsigned or signed?

Comment: @mch unsigned numbers

Comment: I thought I had a solution that started by rearranging the inequality to give `(A[i] - 1) * (A[j] - 1) > 1` but the best I can think of for this is `O(n log n)`.  I think it's the right way to start though.

Comment: What is the O(nlogn) solution you thought?

Comment: Basically, since the array is sorted, you can find, for each `i`,  in `O(log n)` time the least `j`  for which `A[j] - 1 > 1 / (A[i] - 1)` - or the greatest such `j` if `A[i] < 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this was not clearly stated in the question I will make the following two assumptions in the following:

- mirrored pairs are only counted once (otherwise (b,a) is another valid pair if (a,b) is and would thus increase the number of valid pairs)
- entries may not be used twice (eg. (3.01,3.01) is not a valid pair)

Both assumptions can be changed with small variations of the code.

`A` is sorted because `A1` and `A2` are sorted.
For a small example this looks like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   std::vector<double> A({0.1,0.15,0.25,0.29,0.35,0.55,0.65,0.85,1.15,1.44,1.46,1.59,1.88,2.01,2.04,2.05,3.01});
   size_t i=0, j=A.size()-1;
   int result = 0;
   if (A[j] <= 2) return 0;
   while (i != j) {
      if (A[i]*A[j]>A[i]+A[j]) {
        result += j-i;
        cout << A[i] << " to " << A[j] << " for a total of " << result << endl;
        --j;
    } else {
        ++i;
    }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

outputs 8. http://ideone.com/LaV9Cy

This is `O(n)` and works because `A[i+1] > A[i]`, thus `(A[i+1] - 1) * (A[j] - 1) > (A[i] - 1) * (A[j] - 1) > 1` if the second `>` holds. We can therefore simply add the number of elements between the two extremals that we found (`result += j-i;`) instead of trying all of them individually.

Comment: I had a similar idea. However, I tried your solution with `{0.1,0.15,0.25,0.29,0.35,0.55,0.65,0.85,1.15,1.44,1.46,1.59,1.88,2.01,2.04,2.05,3.01}`. Did not work. The result should be 20, but your result is 8.

Comment: @DavidWallace good question. It was more intuitive for me for some reason xD I am probably getting used to seeing iterators. You could use `i` and `j` just as well.

Comment: @gexicide `8` is the number that the first `+= p2-p1` will give (elements between `1.15` and `3.01`), the second one will give another two (`2.01` to `2.05`). You can multiply this by two, if you want to have symmetric pairs (effectively counting every pair twice because (a,b) = (b,a)) and you have your 20.

Comment: @example: What do you mean with "the second one will give another two"? Simply copy pasting your algorithm yields 8, which is wrong. So it seems that your code does not include "the second one".

Comment: I have an odd suspicion that that line that increments `result` should say `result += p2 - p1 + 1;` but I'm not sure now - since I've had so many wrong ideas about this question.

Comment: @DavidWallace: I had the same suspicion :D. Tried it, it yields 5, again wrong :). I also tried `-1` which yields 11, *almost* corrent ;)

Comment: @gexicide are you sure the answer should be 20? How did you come up with that number?

Comment: @example: Of course, you should also count mirrored pairs. If `[3,4]` matches, then so does `[4,3]`. I see no constraint why we should omit these pairs. If we count them, the result is `20`. With your solution, `11` is correct (so you need to insert a `+1`, `8` is incorrect!). It is `11` instead of `10`, because symmetric pairs are not counted twice.

Comment: @gexicide why should it be 11? and why +1? If I am currently comparing the `0`th and `1`st entry, it correctly counts 1 pair. (or *2=2 when exchanging is ok)

Comment: @example: Sorry, I was wrong (and you too), the correct answer must be 12 (not counting symmetric pairs twice). Here are the matching pairs for my example:`(2.01 2.01)
(2.04 2.01)
(2.04 2.04)
(2.05 2.01)
(2.05 2.04)
(2.05 2.05)
(3.01 1.59)
(3.01 1.88)
(3.01 2.01)
(3.01 2.04)
(3.01 2.05)
(3.01 3.01)` Simply count them, they are 12 :)

Comment: The correct answer is in fact 8 http://ideone.com/bmySAI . there are 16 when counting mirrored pairs (a,b) = (b,a). and there are 20 when allowing double indices (a,a) as well. My answer only counts the first variant, for all of the other results small modifications have to be made (eg. a +1)

Comment: @example: Simply count the pairs in my comment. They are 12, not 8!

Comment: @gexicide you chose yet another way of counting: no mirrors, but inlcuding identical entries. Turns out that this question was not at all well defined ;)

Comment: @example: Okay, right :). If anyone is interested, here is how you can get my solution: Replace the `!=` by `>=` and add `+1` to the difference. Then you get 12.

Answer (score 4):

```
x * y > x + y
```

divide by x*y (for positive values)

```
1/x + 1/y < 1
```

Let's the first cursor (R) points to the right element (minimal 1/a[i] value), and the second cursor (L) points to the left element.
Move L to the right until sum of reciprocals reaches 1.
Add (R-L) to result.
Step R to left.
Repeat moving L, until R and L meet each other

Both cursors move at most N steps, so algorithm takes O(N)

Comment: why do we need to step R to left? I am not able comprehend that step. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Sandeep To find additional proper pairs  - when `1/a[R]+1/a[L]` exceeds 1, but `1/a[R-k]+1/a[L+p]` still less than 1